# Apache Permission denied problem on OS X

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, permissions

I get the following log error when I try to run my website locally on my OS X Snow Leopard:

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

I have enabled the virtual hosts and I have the following settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Dropbox/lang/www"
    ServerName llang

    <Directory "/Dropbox/lang/www" >
            Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Where am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache (running as user _www, group _www) must be able to change into `/Dropbox/lang/www` and read files there, either via normal unix rights or ACLs. How do the directory rights look like for `/Dropbox`, `/Dropbox/lang` and `/Dropbox/lang/www` respectively?

Comment: what do i do to get you the answer?

Comment: Open Terminal, enter the following commands and edit your question with the output: `ls -ld /Dropbox`, `ls -ld /Dropbox/lang` etc.

Comment: **`/Dropbox - drwx------@ 18 petarpetrov  admin  612 Jul  6 13:37 /Dropbox`** and **`/Dropbox/lang/ - drwxr-xr-x  13 petarpetrov  admin  442 Jul  6 13:48 /Dropbox/lang/`** and **`/Dropbox/lang/www - drwxr-xr-x  12 petarpetrov  admin  408 Jul  6 17:07 /Dropbox/lang/www/`** What does that tell you?

Comment: This tells me that only the user petarpetrov is allowed to change into the `/Dropbox` directory and due to this, Apache can't read the subdirectories `lang` and `lang/www`. Try `sudo chmod o+rx /Dropbox` and see if this works, but beware that everyone on that machine can read this directory afterwards.

Comment: And isn't there a way to add permissions to a specific user. In this case `_www`? Or is it that this `_www` user has to be either the owner, or in the group owning it?

Comment: If you do a `chgrp _www /Dropbox ; chmod g+rx /Dropbox` instead, it should work as well, yes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Added _www to admin group and then chmoded it with g+rx. **Thanks a lot SvenW**

Comment: Adding _www to the admin group is usually a very bad idea, as Apache is allowed to do everything afterwards. This is a huge security risk and preventing this risk is the reason why Apache is running as _www:_www in the first place. Do it the way I wrote in my last command: Change the group for `/Dropbox` to _www instead and give it read and execute rights.

Comment: i get it, will do